# ESXi 5.0 Embedded Host Client

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm installing an Embedded Host Client for VMware ESXi 5.0.0 build-3982828 from https://labs.vmware.com/flings/esxi-embedded-host-client#instructions

After installation, when I try to reach https:///ui/ it shows 503 Service Unavailable...

Is it not possible to have web interface/embedded host on 5.0 ? Or is it some other kind of problem ?

Comment: 5.5 is the oldest officially supported version so 5.0.0 can behave unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by editing /etc/vmware/hostd/proxy.xml and removing this entry:

```
<e id="2"> 
<_type>vim.ProxyService.LocalServiceSpec</_type> 
<accessMode>httpsWithRedirect</accessMode> 
<por>8308</port> 
<serverNamespace>/ui</serverNamespace> 
</e>
```

also have to recount other entries, and change the <_length> value at the top of the file.